# If for $f$ smooth $F(t)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x,t)$ exists, what is the regularity of $F$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f(x,t)$ be a smooth function in $\mathbb R^2$.

Assume that $F(t)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x,t)$ exists for $t\in[0,1]$.

What do we know about the regularity of $F(t)$ in [0,1]?

Is it continuous? Differentiable? Smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need not be continuous. Let

$$f(x,t) = \arctan (e^{x(t-1/2)}).$$

Then $f$ is smooth on $\mathbb R^2,$ and

$$F(t) = \begin{cases} \pi/2,& t>1/2\\ \pi/4, &t = 1/2\\ 0,& t<1/2 \end{cases}$$